# How to use (op get-global-environment) in exercise 5.42?

Tags: scheme, sicp

I am wondering how to use (op get-global-environment) suggested by the text when the variable is not in the compile time environment.
Since I have to set the env to point to the global-environment,I added save and restore commands but do not feel comfortable because the text always uses preserving to save and restore registers. Here is my code,Any ideas?

```
(define (compile-assignment exp target linkage cmpl-env)

  (let ((var (assignment-variable exp))

        (get-value-code
         (compile (assignment-value exp cmpl-env) 'val 'next))
    (laddr (find-variable var cmpl-env)))
    (end-with-linkage
     linkage
     (preserving '(env)
         get-value-code
         (if (eq? laddr 'not-found)
             (make-instruction-sequence
              '(env val) (list target)
              `((save env)    ;;;here;;;;
            (assign env (op get-global-environment))
                    (perform (op set-variable-value!)
                     (const ,var)
                     (reg val)
                     (reg env))
            (restore env) ;;;and here ;;;;
            (assign ,target (const ok))))
           (make-instruction-sequence
            '(env val) (list target)
            `((perform lexical-address-set! laddr (reg val) (reg env)))
              (assign ,target (const ok)))))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working my way through SICP's exercises I solved 5.42 in a more straightforward way, directly accessing the global environment (thus skipping `(op get-global-environment)` entirely). Writing my solution on top of your code, it looks like this:

```
(if (eq? laddr 'not-found)
    (make-instruction-sequence
     '(env val) (list target)
     `((perform (op set-global-environment!)
                (const ,var)
                (reg val))
       (assign ,target (const ok)))
     (make-instruction-sequence
      '(env val) (list target)
      `((perform (op set-variable-value!)
                 (const ,var)
                 (reg val)
                 (reg env))
        (assign ,target (const ok))))))
```

With the following helper definitions:

```
(define the-global-environment (setup-environment))

(define (set-global-environment! var val)
  (cond ((massq var (first-frame the-global-environment))
         => (lambda (binding) (set-mcdr! binding val)))
        (else (error "Unbound variable -- SET" var))))
```

**Note:** I'm using Racket, in case you're wondering about the `set-mcdr!` part, you can replace it with `set-cdr!` in other Scheme implementations.

Comment: Hi Oscar,Thank you for the answer. I am not familiar with Racket but it seems that you just scan the variable in the first frame of the global environment, any reasons? No possibility for a global variable in frames after the first one?

Comment: IIRC the global definitions reside on the first frame, successive frames are not global but created each time a new scope is needed - so in my implementation it makes sense to search only on the first frame. Anyway that'd be an implementation detail, adapt it to the particular implementation you're aiming for